# How to get the image sizes, in a function, as per the sizes mentioned in the media settings?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm making a custom function for my WordPress site.

```
function mediumFeaturedImage() {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php } else { ?>                                
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/no-image.jpg" alt="No Image Given" width="220" height="145"/>
    <?php }
}
```

I set the `medium` size images to `220 x 145` in `Settings > Media`.

But if you look at the default 'no-image' code block here, I used hard-coded numerals as `width="220" height="145"`. But I want to use this function into some other projects of mine. And I won't use the same settings for medium sized images always. It'll be different from site to site. And always I want my code to be dynamic. Therefore I want a code like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/no-image.jpg" width="<?php $getimagesize('medium','width); ?>" height="<?php $getimagesize('medium','height); ?>"/>
```

It's not mandatory using a function like me. Is there a built-in code like this, that will grab the sizes I assigned in Media settings in WP-Admin, always?

Or, by using the [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) how can I grab the width and height of medium size image only, that assigned for medium sized images in Admin panel?

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want wordpress setting for media

for medium size their are

```
get_option('medium_size_w');//width

get_option('medium_size_h');//height
```

all setting store in options table.[get more media setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference#Media)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) which returns the an array having `width` as index `0`, `height` as index `1` and other attributes.

```
$x = getimagesize('image.jpg');

print_r($x);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 245 <--width
    [1] => 112 <--height
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="245" height="112"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But that will take the grabbed image size, not the site's Large, Medium and Thumbnail image size declarations. Na?