# If image width bigger than height

Tags: images, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making new theme with bootstrap, and having little trouble setting up content. Firstly content is set up like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I need two column layout, images that have width > height are `col-sm-12` or `100%`, and those that are width < height are `col-sm-6` that is `50%`. How can I add function like:

```
if ($w > $h) {
    $class = "col-sm-12";
} else {
    $class = "col-sm-6";
}
```

And also with adding those classes I have to nest columns so all images should be wrapped in `.row` div.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Images are from content editor, in posts, and solution above works but it gives me already set values like `large=1024x1024`, I want natural sizes of images. eg. If my image is `1920x1080` to return those values.

Comment: Where are the images going to come from?

Comment: Is that something you are looking for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102829/22728 ?

Comment: I edited the question, there is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata).

Using your example:

```
$img_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
$w = $img_data['width'];
$h = $img_data['height'];

if ($w > $h) {
    $class = "col-sm-12";
} else {
    $class = "col-sm-6";
}
```

Though, to get the attachment ID, you'll either have to put a filter that acts on every image or create a loop that uses featured images.

Comment: I don't need it for featured images, only content images, and I can't figure out how to get ID for every image, any help?

Comment: Can you insert the images as a gallery?

You can then create your own gallery shortcode to iterate over all the images. Otherwise you have to filter the content.

Comment: Yes, why not, I'l give it a try.

Comment: Acctualy that was a great idea, I found code for customizing galleries, and it worked very well, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802157/change-wordpress-default-gallery-output